# Feature or security loophole in javascript engines

Tags: javascript, security, eval

I was digging a bit in XSS area and found interesting thing in javascript:

```
eval(\`// alert(document.cookie)\`)
```

does nothing as expected, but

```
 eval(\`// \r alert(document.cookie)\`)
```

pops up alert with token... `\r` char whipes out comment and start executing script

tested in IE11, Edge and Chrome, all have same behavior.

Is that something expected? I would consider that as a problem...

Regards,
Evgeny

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/tetocaj/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: SO ate quote marks.... did you put code into `` ?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a question. `eval` will execute any JavaScript passed to it. No-one prefixes `//` to values passed into `eval` - that defeats the purpose of `eval`. What is the exact security hole you feel you've found?

Comment: I just got confused when this worked... that is not what I would expect.. no newline characters, but code got executed... but as Quentin said \r considered as newline in javascript it makes sense to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

A `\r` is a carriage return. It starts a new line.

`//` is a line comment, it only comments out the line it is on.

---

This is no more a security problem than anything else about `eval`. If you use it, you have to understand what input you are giving it.

Comment: ok, looks like just my misunderstanding.. I thought only \n supposed to start new line.. and \r return to the beginning of the line... thanks.

Comment: @Evgeny You can read [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-line-terminators) what JS considers as linebreaks